# Where can I store my suitcase at Madrid Barajas airport?

Tags: luggage-storage, mad

I am looking for some information to find out if there is a place to store suitcase in madrid at barajas airport for couple hours in order to go and visit the city.

Comment: Which terminal do you arrive into, and which do you leave from? (May make a difference to the options)

Answer (score 6):

There are left luggage facilities in the Adolfo Suárez Madrid Barajas airport. Quoting from [the dedicated webpage of the airport website](http://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/eng/left-luggage-office.htm):

> #### Left luggage offices
>
> There are two left luggage office at Madrid Airport.
>
> - Terminal T4, floor 0, arrivals hall.
> - Terminal T1, floor 0, in front of hall 2 in the garden area. This office provides services to terminals T1, T2 and T3.
>
> Contact phone of the luggage office information service at T1 917 466 065.
>
> Contact phone of the luggage office information service at T4 917 466 065.

At the time of writing the price for storing luggage is calculated depending on service usage time. Storing luggage up to 2h costs 6`EUR`, whilst storing luggage for up to 24h and every consecutive day costs 10`EUR` per day. Reduced rates for continuous usage are available.

Answer (score 2):

If you visit the city, it might be a cheaper option to leave your luggage there.  Can't say for sure without knowing your circumstances.

https://www.esmadrid.com/en/left-luggage-facilities-madrid

Comment: are you owner/employee of this company?

Comment: No, I'm not.  I've not even used them myself yet.  I'll only be in Madrid again in a few days from now.  I might need luggage storage myself and thus, this came up in a web search.  The page looks like an an aggregated list of services from several companies anyhow, not a company website.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Left Luggage office in T2 that will save you the hassle of backtracking a 10 min walk.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you have any more information about this office? A precise location, a map, a link?

Comment: The T2 office is mentioned in this link: http://www.aena.es/en/madrid-barajas-airport/luggage.html