# A good place to park / lock / store a bicycle in Madrid for a month?

Tags: bicycles, luggage-storage, madrid

I am going back from Madrid to my home town, then returning to Madrid after a month to fly to South America from there. I have my bicycle which I want to take with me to South America - but won't need my bike in cold winter weather of Estonia in the meantime and flying there and back with the bike with connecting flights is extremely expensive and a very big hassle.

Luggage storage services for a month for such a big item would probably also cost earth, and I don't know anyone in Madrid, so I need to find out if there's a (relatively) safe place to lock and keep my bicycle for that time? Maybe there are some large covered bicycle parking lots where the bike could be parked for a bit longer stay?

Comment: Locking a bicycle for a long period of time on the street and with a "standard lock", someone could notice it and you're probably going to have the bike stolen.

Comment: My first point of look would be the [airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44550/where-can-i-store-my-suitcase-at-madrid-barajas-airport).

Comment: Yep, I did check the airport luggage storage - it would be at least about €200 to store it there.

Comment: Have you asked a friend in Madrid if you can store your cycle with them for a month?

Comment: Yep, I am trying to find someone who could do that using hospitality networks - for now, I don't know anybody there, it's merely my stopping point in travels

Comment: As for airport bicycle parking - providing I have a very good lock and I believe it won't get stolen from there by bike thieves, would the airport security let the bike be there for that amount of time, i.e. could they consider it abandoned, break the lock and take it away?

Comment: Find a bicycle parking which has staff and talk with the people on duty. Mostly they have limits but also have the option for bikes to stay longer in a special area or with a special lock (or whatever their system.) Do not leave your bike in an area with security without talking to those running the checks, as they usually need to take away abandoned bikes.

Comment: Bring it to lost&found and then come back a month later to claim it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on a bicycle tour, consider using [Warmshowers](https://www.warmshowers.org/) (also on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.bitrite.android.ws) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/warmshowers/id359056872?mt=8)). This app/web site connects cycle tourists to people who are willing to host them, usually overnight, but you may also be able to find someone who can store your bike while you go home.